# Hey, they are all under 4

Tags: cipher

Part 1.

> 222123013102101232202311300000113113

That is a cipher.

It's semi-decently hard.

Part 2.

> ..--...-.-..--.-.-.-..-..-.-.-.-..---..-..---..-.-.-.---.-...-....--..--..--..--.-.-......--..-...--.---.-...--..-...--..-...-...-..--.-.-.-.--..-.-.-.-.-.-.-...-..-.-...--..-...--..-..-..----.-....--..--.-...-..-....-..-.--..--.---.-.-..--.-..-..-.-.-.--..-.....-..--..--.-.-.--..-....-..-.-.-...-.-.-.-.-..-....-...---.-..---...---..-.-....-..-.....-.-....--.-...---..---..-..--.---.-..----.-..----.-...--...--.-....--.....-....--..--.-....--...-..--.---..--.-.-.-.-..--.-..--...-..--....--.-.-.-..-..-..--..--.-..--.-..---..-.-..---..-.-..-...--..--.-..--.-.-.-.---.-..----.-.-.-.-..--.-...-..-.-..-...-.-.-.-.--..-.....-.-.....-.-....-..-...---..--.-.-.-..----

Hints for part 1:

1

> The title is significant, but you could figure it out without it.

2

> 4, 16, 2.5.

3

> There's a base to this problem. Or should it be bases....

Hints for part 2.

1

> That doesn't look like morse code....

2

> Maybe I'm missing a couple of spaces...

3

> Part 1 is correlated with Part 2.

Comment: This is taking longer than expected...

Comment: Usually with puzzles of this nature, they simply aren't interesting enough to draw in solvers. What motivation does one have to attempt an arbitrary number of decryption methods on this string of digits?

Comment: @IanMacDonald For the number of Favoriters and Voters, a lot.

Comment: Ok, All, I'm going to expand the puzzle.

Comment: I think one thing about these puzzles is that they typically lack intermediate positive reinforcement.  I mean, I had (most of) hints 1-3 figured out before they were posted, but I just ended up trying a bunch of transforms and nothing was working for me.  If the question somehow incorporated hints that helped validate intermediate steps it'd be a lot more friendly.

Comment: Oh actually I just realized that you updated the number...so maybe I was on the right track, but with the wrong data.

Comment: I think this puzzle deserves closure (solution).

Answer (score 3):

The `4, 16, 2.5` clue makes me think it combines base 4 and base 16 and then base 10 in some way (since 4 × 2.5 = 10). We know that the cipher string is encoded in base 4, but if we convert it to base 10, we get:

> 3130313130312032323031

And if we take pairs of these digits as hex code and convert it to ASCII, we get:

> 101101 2201

One of these appears to be in base 2 while the other is in base 3. They evaluate to 45 and 73 respectively, which appears to be the answer (the ordered pair `(45, 73)`) based on discussions in chat.

---

Part 2:

If we convert the dots to 0 and dashes to 1, we get binary ASCII again:

> 1MRU99WD33P27FFDMVUTJ22OC4HK7SIVA3VBTUHGN9BACG97OOF40C4175SLL5I3M9NR3MWOU4JEVAABG5O

Haven't worked it out past this yet.

Comment: Please advise as to whether I'm on the right track?

Comment: no, the ? mark is off. No multiplying either.

Comment: I know the ? is off, because the character that's actually there isn't printable. What I'm asking is if there's supposed to be a character there at all.

Comment: No, you took the 2nd clue completely wrong.

Comment: So all my partial deciphers and everything are incorrect?

Comment: Yep.... shucks.

Comment: Welp. Interesting coincidence at any rate.

Comment: Not a coincidence..... you are 10% on the right track after hints actually.

Comment: Actually its just your hex converter.

Comment: What my Quaternary converter is bad sorry...

Comment: What should the ciphertext be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39770/discussion-between-bleh-and-joe-z).